# How create video thumbnail image for preview on scroll bar

Tags: javascript, image, ffmpeg, video-processing, preview

I see this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-preview-thumbnails that allow to create a video preview thumbnails on scrollbar, my question is, how is the fast way to create a image that contain all images frames in order to use this plugin.
I try to use ffmpeg but create only separated image and i need to merge them in a single image.